# pagination with different url for each page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have this .js file for the pagination in html anybody can help me what i have to change to show the different url for each page & user can save that url & can use it for future use to go on that specific page.

(.js file start from below)

```
function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage) {
this.tableName = tableName;
this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
this.currentPage = 1;
this.pages = 0;
this.inited = false;

this.showRecords = function(from, to) {        
    var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
    // i starts from 1 to skip table header row
    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        if (i < from || i > to)  
            rows[i].style.display = 'none';
        else
            rows[i].style.display = '';
    }
}

this.showPage = function(pageNumber) {
    if (! this.inited) {
        alert("not inited");
        return;
    }

    var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
    oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';

    this.currentPage = pageNumber;
    var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
    newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';

    var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;
    var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;
    this.showRecords(from, to);
}   

this.prev = function() {
    if (this.currentPage > 1)
        this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1);
}

this.next = function() {
    if (this.currentPage < this.pages) {
        this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1);
    }
}                        

this.init = function() {
    var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
    var records = (rows.length - 1); 
    this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
    this.inited = true;
}

this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, positionId) {
    if (! this.inited) {
        alert("not inited");
        return;
    }
    var element = document.getElementById(positionId);

    var pagerHtml = '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> &#171 Prev </span> | ';
    for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++) 
        pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + page + '</span> | ';
    pagerHtml += '<span onclick="'+pagerName+'.next();" class="pg-normal"> Next &#187;</span>';            

    element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `this.showPage()` update the url hash with something like "pg=1":

```
location.hash = "#pg=" + pageNumber;
```

That method will add an item to your page history.  If you don't want to add an item to your page history, use this:

```
location.replace("#pg=" + pageNumber);
```

Then, when the page is loaded, after you call `pager.init()`, you'll want to call `pager.showPage()`.  You can use this code to decide whether to load the first page or the page from the url::

```
var page = /\bpg=(\d+)\b/.test(location.hash) ? parseInt(RegExp.$1) : 1;
pager.showPage(page);
```

Comment: @ gilly3, thanks for your help, but with this (location.hash = "#pg=" + pageNumber;) in url it's showing page no for each page but viewer can't recall the specific page by saving the url & use it next time. have any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Abdul - I assumed that `Pager.init()` was called when the page loads.  Is that right?  And do you have the RegExp test and `showPage()` call in `Pager.init()`?

Comment: yeah `pager.init` called when the page loads. but i don't know about RegExp test & i also past these lines in Pager.init like this `this.init = function() {
  var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        var records = (rows.length - 1); 
        this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
        this.inited = true;
  if (/\bpg=(\d+)\b/.test(location.hash))
  this.showPage(RegExp.$1);
  }`

Comment: @Abdul - Right after you call `init()` are you then calling `showPage()`?

Comment: @Abdul - I've updated my answer.  Remove the regex test and the call to `showPage` from `this.init()`.  Instead, move that logic to your page onload handler.

Comment: now this.init code it like this `this.init = function() {
  var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
  var records = (rows.length - 1); 
  this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
  this.inited = true;
  var page = /\bpg=(\d+)\b/.test(location.hash) ? RegExp.$1 : 1;}`

and on html page `<script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var pager = new Pager('results', 2); 
        pager.init(); 
        pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition'); 
  pager.showPage(page);
//--></script>`
on page load it shows coplete table & on clicking on other page it show only specific area

Comment: & if i load the directly 2nd page from give the url then it again shows the complete table

Comment: Move the line `var page = /\bpg=(\d+)\b/.test(location.hash) ? RegExp.$1 : 1;` into your html page above the line `pager.showPage(page);`.

Comment: @Abdul - Also, you may want to call `parseInt()` around `RegExp.$1` in the `var page = ...` line.  I've updated my answer with that suggestion.

Comment: @Abdul - `RegExp.$1` returns a string, but you want a number.  JavaScript will sometimes convert a string to a number for you, but not always.  For example `"10" - 1` returns the number `9`, but `"10" + 1` returns the string `"101"`.  In this code, it looks like you probably won't see any issues passing in a string.  But it's safer to convert the string to a number.  `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` are the ways to do that.

Comment: @gilly3 - i created the video library with this pagination technique, now I want when user click on any page,, page view go on Top of the page or top of the Table, (Please help me in this Issue)